# C# connection to Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I have been doing applications on Java, connected with MySQL, but now I am doing C# with Oracle. 
Here is the code I've got so far:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace Chat
{
    class DBconnector
    {
        static private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return "Data Source=myserver.server.com;Persist Security Info=True;" +
                "User ID=myUserID;Password=myPassword;Unicode=True";
        }
        static public void ConnectAndQuery()
        {

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("State: " + conn.State);
                Console.WriteLine("Connction String: " + conn.ConnectionString);

                OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["MYFIELD"];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

What is hacking me is that I don't know what to type in exchange of "myserver.server.com", "myUserID" and the "myPassword" in the connectionString. 
I suppose it's "localhost/" and smth like that, but with Oracle I don't really have the same visual interface as with MySQL in the browser and thus I am kinda' lost.

I followed this tutorial: [Instant Oracle using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18692/Instant-Oracle-Using-C)
and I am doing the case with including the connection String directly in my code, but not using the tsanames.ora external file. 
Long story short -> I am not sure how to modify the connection string for my own database and if there are any other mistakes or suggestions - feel free to state them.

Comment: You should use the TNSNAMES.ORA file.

Comment: Use my favourite website http://connectionstrings.com/oracle . This has always helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this without modifying your tnsnames, but it's not hard:

```
YOURSERVER = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL= TCP)
(Host= <your_server_hostname_or_IP>)(Port= <port>))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = <DB_instance name>)) )
```

If you have doubts on how to fill these up, you should check with your nearest DBA.

Then just add YOURSERVER in:

```
return "Data Source=YOURSERVER; ...
```

Username and password are those related to the schema you want to connect.